# How can CDI event in a EAR fires and observe from different EAR in same JVM?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I have tested this scenario, with CDI event in one EAR get triggers and consumer can invoke as long as it is same EAR. Is CDI event is limited to its EAR package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Chapter 12 of CDI Spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/packagingdeployment.html):

> The **container searches for beans** in all bean archives in the
>   application classpath:
>        In an application deployed as an ear, the container searches every bean archive bundled with or referenced by the ear, including
>   bean archives bundled with or referenced by wars and EJB jars
>   contained in the ear. The bean archives might be library jars, EJB
>   jars, rars or war WEB-INF/classes directories.

So - yes, CDI event is limited to its EAR package.

[5.5.6. Invocation of observer methods](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/injectionelresolution.html#observers)

> If the observer method is static, the **container must invoke** the
>   method.
>
> Otherwise, if the observer method is non-static, **the container must**:
>   ...

Comment: in CDI 1.1 in application scope it can able to share theoretically.